# Export Flash Pro CS6 to Js

Tags: flash, flash-cs6

How do you export a Flash Pro file to js instead of swf?

I'm using Flash Pro CS6 and I want to implement it to a webpage.

Thanks!

Comment: Just press "File" and then "Publish" :)

Comment: Nothing happens when I publish :(

Comment: in your project folder now you have `.html` file , run it

Comment: I have a swf and html file. how do i save it as js? for publishing?

Comment: hmm, may be this is relevant: http://www.adobe.com/products/flash/flash-to-html5.html

Comment: Oh. So that means I need CreateJS? Are they free?

Comment: i don't know, didn't try that